# How to convert the printed results below to dataframe using beautifulsoup on Yahoo Screener?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The below code will provide me a range of Price intraday for most active stock on Yahoo Screener

How do I convert them create into a data frame ?

Thanks!

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://in.finance.yahoo.com/most-active'
header = {'User-Agent': 's'}
response=requests.get(url,headers=header)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    print(item.select('[aria-label=Symbol]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    print(item.select('[aria-label="Name"]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
      print(item.select('[aria-label="Change"]')[0].get_text())
   
for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
      print(item.select('[aria-label="% change"]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
      print(item.select('[aria-label="Market cap"]')[0].get_text())
   
for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
      print(item.select('[aria-label="Avg vol (3-month)"]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
      print(item.select('[aria-label="Volume"]')[0].get_text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a defaultdict with list and append to the list of each key in the dict.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
from collections import defaultdict

url='https://in.finance.yahoo.com/most-active'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
response=requests.get(url,headers=header)
soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

data = defaultdict(list)

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Symbol"].append(item.select('[aria-label=Symbol]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Name"].append(item.select('[aria-label="Name"]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Change"].append(item.select('[aria-label="Change"]')[0].get_text())
   
for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["% change"].append(item.select('[aria-label="% change"]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Market cap"].append(item.select('[aria-label="Market cap"]')[0].get_text())
   
for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Avg vol (3-month)"].append(item.select('[aria-label="Avg vol (3-month)"]')[0].get_text())

for item in soup.select('.simpTblRow'):
    data["Volume"].append(item.select('[aria-label="Volume"]')[0].get_text())

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          Symbol                                   Name   Change % change Market cap Avg vol (3-month)    Volume
0         IDEA.NS                  Vodafone Idea Limited    -0.05   -0.57%   249.132B          502.413M  328.466M
1      YESBANK.NS                       Yes Bank Limited    +0.25   +2.08%    306.41B           71.135M  156.316M
2   TATAMOTORS.NS                    Tata Motors Limited    -1.60   -1.42%   364.219B           68.231M   95.878M
3         IDEA.BO                  Vodafone Idea Limited    -0.09   -1.03%   247.987B           97.612M   69.686M
4       532822.BO                  Idea Cellular Limited    -0.09   -1.03%    37.643B            1.056M   69.686M
5         ZEEL.NS  Zee Entertainment Enterprises Limited    +8.40   +6.22%   137.688B           25.077M   48.852M
6   TRIDENT-BL.NS                            TRIDENT LTD     0.00    0.00%        N/A               N/A       48M
7         SBIN.NS                    State Bank of India    -0.65   -0.34%      1.71T           71.068M   43.854M
8     RELIANCE.NS            Reliance Industries Limited  +141.60   +7.05%    14.542T            22.74M   42.474M
9    FCONSUMER.NS                Future Consumer Limited    +0.05   +0.43%    22.415B           10.807M   37.696M
10        BHEL.NS       Bharat Heavy Electricals Limited    +0.45   +1.24%   127.618B           81.129M   34.053M
11  IDFCFIRSTB.NS                IDFC First Bank Limited    +0.70   +2.68%   152.019B           46.588M   32.774M
12   ICICIBANK.NS                     ICICI Bank Limited    +7.75   +2.26%     2.272T            47.26M   30.789M
13    HDFCBANK.NS                      HDFC Bank Limited   +39.65   +3.96%     5.719T           18.522M   30.149M
14     VEDL-EQ.NS                        VEDANTA LIMITED    +3.75   +3.25%        N/A               N/A   25.879M
15        VEDL.NS                        Vedanta Limited    +3.75   +3.25%   440.937B           29.171M   25.879M
16     YESBANK.BO                       Yes Bank Limited    +0.24   +2.00%   306.171B            5.735M   26.218M
17      532648.BO                       Yes Bank Limited    +0.24   +2.00%    28.138B            1.105M   26.218M
18        BPCL.NS   Bharat Petroleum Corporation Limited    -9.25   -2.21%   886.141B           10.576M   25.606M
19         IOC.NS         Indian Oil Corporation Limited    +0.75   +0.87%   818.561B           22.285M   25.488M
20   TATAPOWER.NS         The Tata Power Company Limited    +0.95   +1.95%   134.427B           37.715M   25.277M
21    AXISBANK.NS                      Axis Bank Limited   +11.80   +2.83%     1.211T           40.473M   24.738M
22  BANKBARODA.NS                         Bank of Baroda    -0.35   -0.75%   214.857B            41.54M   24.648M
23        RCOM.NS        Reliance Communications Limited  -0.1000   -3.51%     8.977B            8.014M    22.86M
24    ASHOKLEY.NS                  Ashok Leyland Limited    +0.30   +0.61%   145.602B           42.522M   22.224M
```